# move server to different physical network without changing ip address

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, virtual-machines, ip-address

I have a set of 4 virtual machines (server 2008r2) that I need to move to a new data center which cannot have their IP addresses changed. I've tried for months to get the vendor to change them, but the software is so horribly designed that it's just not possible. At the moment, I'm exploring some network options but if I could handle this on the server somehow I'd prefer to do that.

Right now the servers are on the 192.168.0.0/24 network and they need to be moved to the 192.168.10.0/24 network. Is there any way to use a loopback adapter to accomplish this or perhaps some other method? I'm certainly open to all suggestions.

I should point out that the move is to a geographically different location.

[image: Network Diagram]

Comment: Connect them to a Layer 3 switch, configure a VLAN for the switch ports they're connected to, and enable/configure inter-VLAN routing?

Comment: They would be in different physical locations so I can't do that. I thought about stretching a VLAN across the WAN, but that would create more problems than its worth. I proposed this question a while ago somewhere else and someone mentioned they had a solution using a loopback adapter on Windows. Unfortunately they never replied after that so I have no clue what they were getting at.

Comment: I'm not understanding what the physical location has to do with it. Let's say, for example, that the provider is giving you a 10.0.0.0/8 address block to work with. You configure the L3 switch with a VLAN for these servers, enable/configure inter-VLAN routing on the switch, and route traffic to and from these servers in the switch to and from the provider network space that's been allocated to you. Why would a stretched VLAN even be in play?

Comment: OK, I wasn't quite getting the full picture without the diagram. Assuming that you need to move those servers and maintain connectivity/routability between them and every other network/device without changing the ip addresses of the servers, you might look into static host routes on the routers for those 2 servers and then configure a VLAN and inter-VLAN routing like I described.

Comment: How could I use inter-VLAN routing over 802.1q though?

Comment: If I was able to help you, could you please mark my answer as accepted by clicking on `v` under the answer's score. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you'd prefer to don't touch configuration of the moving server at all, your best bet would be a **LAN-to-LAN VPN (Using L2 Bridge)**

One side of this VPN will be your original 192.168.0.0/24 LAN and another side will be LAN just from your server 192.168.0.100.

Pros of this solution will be that you don't need to touch network settings on your servers and clients. Everything will be totally transparent.

Cons are that all communications to your 192.168.0.100 server will be going through 192.168.0.0/24 router and VPN bridges - even for the servers in 192.168.10.0/24 segment. I.E. the 192.168.10.0/24 LAN and 192.168.0.100 server will not see each other directly, even being stationed on the same site.

Read more about this solution on the website of [SoftEther VPN](https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/A._Examples_of_Building_VPN_Networks/10.5_Build_a_LAN-to-LAN_VPN_(Using_L2_Bridge)) project.

Alternatively you could try implementing a dialup VPN from your 192.168.0.100 server to 192.168.0.0/24 network, but that would require additional configurations on the server itself.

[image: Network Layout]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sergey, but I'm not sure if this is going to work for unfortunately. The performance impact would likely be too great. I might give it a shot none-the-less.